# Rails controller naming convention postsComments or postComments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, naming, convention

If I'd like to generate a controller for comments that belongs to a post which in turn belongs to a user, should I name this

```
rails g controller postsComments
```

Or

```
rails g controller postComments
```

Or

```
rails g controller postcomments
```

Or just

```
rails g controller comments
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you type,

```
 rails g controller
```

you'll get detailed instructions and an example of how to do it correctly. Basically, you can use either `CamelCase` or `under_scored` and the result will be the same. `under_scores` in file names and `CamelCase` in class names.

As for the name, I'd personally use `Comments`, unless you plan to have another type of comments in your app and want to use a different class name for them.

And finally the question whether you should use `PostsComments` or `PostComments` is more about the english language than Rails. I think the more correct way would be `PostComments`, but I'm not a native speaker :)

Comment: native speaker here: i've debated the semantics and minutae for a few minutes, considering possession and have come at it from every possible angle, and have concluded, to keep it simple: PostComments is your best bet here and probably the simplest.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the `rails g controller PostComments` command, post singularized because Post has_many Comments & Comment has_one Post.